# Matrix - how to "Populate the menu from another channel field"?

Tags: matrix, custom-fields, fieldtype, fields

EE's native `Select Dropdown` field has the option to "Populate the menu from another channel field". I'm using Matrix and the `P&T Dropdown` field. It doesn't have the option to "Populate the menu from another channel field". I want to populate the list from another channel field. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MX Select Plus](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-select) is a great fieldtype–you can choose either to populate the menu with plain text or write a SQL query. It's pretty slick!

Comment: Actually, now I realize that what I actually need is a Relationship field in the Matrix. Suggestions?

Comment: Playa. I don't know if the native relationship works with matrix.

Answer (score 0):

[Playa](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/playa) might just be the addon you might be looking for!